# Efficient way of storing 10^12 digits and checking individual digits in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, time, memory-efficient

I am doing a project where I am making a solver for the game mastermind.

In this version, there are 10 possible digits (1-9) and the answer is a length of 12. Therefore, I have to store 10^12 digits.

In the game of mastermind, you must be able to know the individual digits to make a better guess. Using an array is impossible for this size and a tree of digits takes too much time (the answer must be solved in under 5 minutes).

What are some good ways of storing so much information and also being able to check the digits within each number?

Comment: 1-9 is 10 digits? "Therefore I have to store..." - that does not quite follow. You can't even loop through all those in the time you have, which means the solution has to take a different path.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a tree of digits takes too much time". Or what *specific* problem you're trying to solve--why do you need to store all possible solutions?

Comment: Hi, I don't quite get why you would need to store 10^12 digits (assuming you meant 0-9). Yes, there are 10^12 possible solutions, but why do you want to store them all at the same time?

Comment: You might want to consider a more human-like approach, which requires only tracking your previous guesses and the right-color/wrong-place and right-color/right-place feedback. If you're gunning for the canonical Knuth solution consider that just because the original algo generated all the guesses "up front" there's likely no reason they couldn't be generated on an as-needed basis.

Comment: "Using an array is impossible for this size" - Really? How so? Assume you store these "digits" in a `String`. Isn't a `String` an array of characters? Your problem is your logic (math) really bad. You don't need 10^12 digits stored.

Comment: @hfontanez I believe the algo OP is looking at is old Knuth, which pre-gens all possible solutions. The number of solutions for a 12-digit 1-9 MasterMind is 9^12, which is a big number. If the OP is following Knuth precisely, it *would* require storing the solutions--OP's math is fine (delta the wrong number of digits) based on their initial approach, it's just that this approach doesn't work for giant MMs.

Comment: @DaveNewton you might be right. But his explanation is so vague, that's not what I got from it. Remember, he wrote: "I am making a solver for the game mastermind" and if that is the real intent, he doesn't need to store n^m solutions.

Comment: @hfontanez Yes, I still remember.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why you would want to do that, but ignoring that, let's imagine what a solution looks like. You write twelve digits from left to right. What does it look like? Like an integral number with 12 decimal places, right? So all you need is a data type that is big enough to hold such big numbers.

So, a long perfectly fits your requirement. it takes exactly 8 bytes.

The rest depends on what information you want to store for each combination of digits. You can use the long as a key into a map (array indexes are currently still restricted to integer, so that won't work). If you do that, you could look for a special library that offers maps with primitive types as keys since that would save you a lot of memory in this special case. Examples for such libraries are [GNU Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html) and [Fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it).

Comment: This smells like a homework problem, not a real-world problem. So, the intent of the problem is not to figure out an efficient storage (data structure), but in using flow control, maybe converting (casting) characters into `ints`, etc.